# Comparing Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

Was wondering if there's a way to compare a set of data inside an array all at once. I'm currently making a JPEG image recovery program from a homework, I hard coded the JPEG byte pattern and it looks a bit messy.

It would really help me if I can gather suggestions on how to tidy this code up. The problem starts in the if condition inside the while loop.

The byte pattern that I want to check is 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 or 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1

```
#define BLOCKSIZE 512

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // create a buffer of 512 Bytes
    BYTE buffer[BLOCKSIZE];

    // open card, check if fopen is successful 
    FILE* card = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (card == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open card.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // scan through card, 1 block at a time (512 Bytes) until end of file
    while (fread(&buffer, BLOCKSIZE, 1, card) == 1)
    {
        // read current buffer
        fread(&buffer, BLOCKSIZE, 1, card);

        // check if current buffer marks the start of a JPEG pattern
        if ((buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] == 0xe0) ||
            (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] == 0xe1))

    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in a function. Name it something descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this a bit:

```
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3]&0xfe) == 0xe0))
```

That is, combine the common parts, and use a mask to hide the bit you don't care about when checking `buffer[3]`.

You can also use `memcmp` to compare 2 different blocks of memory (in your case, one would be the run you want to test against).

Comment: Why not read `uint32_t`, mask bit, compare to 32 bit constant?

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for the suggestion! I'll also look into memcmp!

Comment: @dom0: How sure are you that `buffer` is aligned?

Comment: @dom0: and endianess issue.

Comment: Can someone explain this part further? I'm fairly new and I'm quite confused with this code.
.
.
'(buffer[3]&0xfe) == 0xe0)'

Comment: @HeroStradivari: `0xe0` and `0xe1` have identical bit patterns, except for the least significant bit (lsb), which is `0` in the case of `0xe0`, and `1` in the case of `0xe1`. The bit pattern for `0xfe` is `11111110`, so the result of doing a bitwise AND (`&`) with `0xfe` is to clear the lsb, and leave all other bits unmodified.  So, the result of `0xe0 & 0xfe` is `0xe0` (it does nothing, since the lsb is already clear in `0xe0`). And the result of `0xe1 & 0xfe` is also `0xe0`. So, the operation `buffer[3] & 0xfe` will produce 0xe0 if and only if `buffer[3]` is equal to either `0xe0` or `0xe1`.

Answer (score 1):

Is using a byte array necessary here? Since you are checking 4 bytes, you could use a `uint32_t buffer[BLOCKSIZE / 4]`

From there, you need to make sure `fread()` is reading int-wise.

`fread(&buffer, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, card); // untested code`

Then you check: `if buffer[0] == 0xffd8ffe0 || **I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader**`

Also, calling `fread()` twice might not have the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: From the specification, we need to scan 512 Bytes at a time since CF cards uses that as blocks, and is stored one after another. The four bytes check is my way of knowing if it's a start of a JPEG.


Thank you for pointing that I was calling fread twice. I'm fairly new to FILE I/O, and still learning. I read that using while feof(*fp) was a bad idea since it will do another walk in the loop after knowing it's the end of the file. May I get some suggestion on what I should do instead?

Comment: Since I am dividing BLOCKSIZE by 4, you are only scanning 512 bytes of data. My solution also checks 4 bytes, just in a less verbose way. sizeof(4 Bytes) = sizeof(32 bit integer).